# send data to email view cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

I want to send email with cakephp.

But I want send in the email with lot of data like

```
'Envoie' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '59',
            'compte_id' => '1',
            'annonce_id' => '19',
            'site_id' => '8',
            'valider' => '0',
            'lien' => null,
            'created' => '2013-09-19 15:56:28'
        ),
```

in my code i have this

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
                $Email->template('default', 'a');
                $envoie = $this->Envoie->find('all',array('conditions' => array(
                                        'Envoie.annonce_id' =>$annonce['Annonce']['id'])));
                $Email->viewVars(array("envoie"=>$envoie));
                $Email->emailFormat('html');
                $Email->to('email@hotmail.com');//$annonce['User']['username']
                $Email->from('no-repley@domaine.com');
                $Email->subject('subject');
                $Email->send();
```

How i can send my table to my view ?

Comment: You are already doing it, you should have access to a $envoie variable in your email view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $envoie array in your view ie app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp.
For example, you can get value of id using $envoie['id'] and so on...

Answer (score 2):

In your email template

```
app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp
```

You already have access to $envoie, just extract the variable's values to your needs.